# Make sure control stay in their zone in multilang interface

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, controls

I have a layout which I am trying to make multilingual, but with the transition comes some hurdles.

English:

[image]

German:

[image]

As you can see the checkbox is flying around in the grid, how can I sort this to not clash with other controls?

Thanks

EDIT with XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="Block" Margin="23,70,24.002,153">
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFDDDDDD" Stroke="#FFD7D7D7" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FFE8E8E8" Margin="0,19,0,0" Stroke="#FFD7D7D7"/>
            <Label Height="22" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.settings]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" Foreground="#FF585858"/>
            <TextBox MaxLength="2" x:Name="textTimeMin" Margin="175.145,34.336,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" Style="{DynamicResource style1Text}" Height="25.2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30"/>
            <TextBox MaxLength="2" x:Name="textTimeHour" Margin="132.868,34.336,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" Style="{DynamicResource style1Text}" Height="25.2"/>
            <Label Content=":" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="162.868,35,0,0" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF585858" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.timeOptions1]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6.148,36.332,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF585858" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" Height="23.2"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.timeOptions2]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6.148,67.999,0,52.799" FontSize="11" Foreground="#FF585858" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" Height="23.202"/>
            <Custom:DatePicker x:Name="pickerDate" Margin="134,68.149,188,51.851" d:LayoutOverrides=", Height" FontFamily="Myriad Pro" IsTodayHighlighted="False" Foreground="#FF585858"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnAddTask" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.addTask]}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,0,0,8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{DynamicResource style1Btn}" Click="btnAddTask_Click" Height="24.65"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="checkIgnoreDate" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.ignoreDate]}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,105,55.706" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="#FF585858" Background="{x:Null}" Checked="checkIgnoreDate_Checked" Unchecked="checkIgnoreDate_Unchecked" Height="15.96"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="ignoreDateStrike" Fill="#FF444444" Height="1" Margin="6.148,0,199.32,64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnNow" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation}, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[Language.now]}" Margin="206.088,34.27,176.585,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource style1Btn}" Height="25.2" FontSize="9.333" Click="btnNow_Click"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: It depends on the kind of layout you're using. With a fluid layout (easy with WPF) it should change its position without overlapping. If you're using a canvas then you'll get all kind of troubles for this stuffs...

Comment: I've added the XAML I am using for my layout, any recommendations?

Comment: Do not use margins for your layout. There are a lot of options, you may use the grid or the easy-to-use StackPanel to stack each line and then each row of controls. The _bad_ is that you have to change your (code for) layout a lot...

Comment: Just as I saw your comment I had ended up starting to change my code to use stackpanels, I guess this is the best way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your screenshots and your code, there are a few different ways you could go about this.

I would recommend using a grid with three columns and three rows, where the columns are autosized. That will ensure that everything lines up nicely and fits nicely regardless of how long your fields are.

[image]

Your grid code would look something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Block">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
...   
</Grid>
```

You then just have to set an appropriate row and column for each item inside the grid, instead of hardcoding their margins.

```
   <Button x:Name="btnAddTask" Grid.Row="1" .... />
```